# Two numbers from any 51 integers must differ by 50?? (Textbook error?)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, divisibility

I found a question in *1001 Problems in Classical Number Theory* by Jean-Marie De Koninck *et. al.*(1) that seems to be in error. Question #30 reads:

> (30) Given 51 arbitrary positive integers, show that one can always find two of them whose difference is 50.

This seems obviously false, because, for example, the sequence { 100, 200, 300, ..., 5100 } will never contain two numbers that differ by 50.

The solution given in the text seems to hint at their actual intent:

> (30) There are exactly 50 possible remainders when we divide the numbers by 50, and these remainders are the numbers: 0, 1, 2, ..., 49. Since we have 51 integers and only 50 possible remainders, it follows that using the Pigenhole Principle, there are at least two numbers amongst these 51 integers having the same remainder. Then, the difference of these two integers has 0 as a remainder and is therefore divisible by 50.

**My question** is simply: is the textbook question invalid/wrong? (i.e., am I correct in believing there is no such sequence?) If the question *is* valid, can you provide an example of a valid sequence that satisfies the question? If I'm right and the question is invalid, confirmation will suffice, although any additional evidence or explanation would be appreciated.

If I may indulge in brief speculation, I would guess that, based on their solution, the authors probably intended the question to read:

> ... one can always find two of them whose difference is **divisible by** 50.

But I'd be most grateful for someone else's interpretation of the question and the solution.

---

(1). ISBN 978-0-8218-4229-9

Comment: Yes, they intended it to read the way you have stated.  Of course, the original question was wrong by some distance.

Comment: The answer is a correct answer to a different question.  It's conclusion is something different than what was stated and the reasoning doesn't apply.  It's like asking "do penguins get enough calcium in their diets" and answering "answering penguins diets consist of fish, then, yes penguins must spend time in the water".  So, yes, it's probably an editing oversight.

Comment: @SubhadeepDey It's cyrillic writing for "Aston Villa" "Olof Mellberg" (a football club and a football player). A fan, I suppose?

Comment: Thanks everyone (please consider writing some of these up as answers so I have something to upvote/accept!) I also just noticed that this question #30 is in a chapter entitled "Divisibility", so it's probably looking even better for a simple omission of "divisible by" in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

community wiki post so the question can be closed

You are correct.  The authors intended to state that in any set of $51$ positive integers, there must be two whose difference is divisible by $50$.